# AutoLISP function bad argument in AutoCAD

Tags: lisp, autocad, autolisp

> ```
> (defun gml2dwg (odabir)
>
>     ;; RANDOM CODE ;;
>     ;; This is the part where I should open a filepath "odabir" 
>     (setq datoteka (open odabir "r"))
>
>     ;; CODE IS CONTINUED )
>
> (defun c:gml2dwg (/ odabir)   
>     (setq odabir (getstring "Odabir:"))  
>     (gml2dwg odabir)   
>     (princ) )
>
> (defun c:gmlimport (/ allfiles fpath)   
>      (setq allfiles (vl-directory-files "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\gml2" "*.gml"))  
> (foreach file allfiles
>     ((setq fpath (strcat "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\gml2\\" file))
>     (gml2dwg fpath))   )
>       (princ) )
> ```

So, as shown above, i have first long lisp function gml2dwg that get a gml file as an input and draws the polygons from the file in autocad. The function can only take one file as an input, so I have problems inputing 6000+ gml files into cad. I wrote two other functions, where c:gml2dwg is the one able to take parameters since gml2dwg can't be used as a command. The third - c:gmlimport is used to get all files from a directory and loop it through the c:gml2dwg, but all I get is this error:

> ********* Pogreška: bad argument type: stringp nil! ********** Cannot invoke (command) from *error* without prior call to
>   (*push-error-using-command*). Converting (command) calls to
>   (command-s) is recommended.

The first function works fine in the form of calling it in the VLISP console (gml2dwg "somefilepath"). 
Can anyone tell me what is wrong in the other two functions? It's something with arguments/parameters probably or setting the variables, but I'm an amateur in lisp so I need your help to figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: Show an [MCVE] in your question. In its current form, it cannot be answered since unclear. Also, format better your code, with at least four spaces before each code line. So **edit your question** to improve it much more.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Fixed.

Comment: No, not yet. Code should be typed with four spaces in front of every line, and you should give *both* scripts as an [MCVE] which other readers can *easily* reproduce. Even with the edit, your (badly formatted) question does not show an [MCVE]. Read more about [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Without a lot of improvement your question will be closed as unclear. I reformatted some of the code, but you'll better also reformat the error message, give more code, and edit again your question

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm new on the site. Repaired the code, but there's no need to put the first script since it's long (and I mentioned it is working + its parameters) and the only problem is non-working foreach function in the second script.

Comment: You won't put *your* first script, you'll put a *simplified, minimal* version to get an [MCVE]. Without an [MCVE] your question will be closed. Please follow that [MCVE] link

Answer (score 1):

If I don't misunderstand, gml2dwg is a LISP defined command :

```
(defun c:gml2dwg ...)
```

If so, you cannot call gml2dwg with the command function and pass it arguments.
You need to split the c:gml2dwg function into 2 functions:

1) a standard LISP function which takes 2 arguments: some option ("k"?) and the file path. This function contains the code which draws the polygon according to the arguments.

```
(defun gml2dwg (option fpath) ...)
```

2) a LISP defined command which gets user inputs and call the gml2dwg function passing it the results of inputs.

```
(defun c:gml2dwg (/ option fpath ...)
  (setq option ...)
  (setq fpath ...)
  (gml2dwg option fpath)
  (princ)
)
```

This way, you can call the gml2dwg function from c:gmlimport:

```
(defun c:gmlimport (/ allfiles fpath)
  (setq allfiles (vl-directory-files
           "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\gml2"
           "*.gml"
         )
  )
  (foreach file allfiles
    (setq fpath (strcat "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\gml2\\" file))
    (gml2dwg "k" fpath)
  )
  (princ)
)
```

Note: I removed a superfluous opening parenthesis.

Comment: Yes, thanks for answering. That should be the problem, but I can't manage to get the script work since I'm new to lisp. Can you check the post update so you can tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's still a superfluous parenthesis before (setq fpath ...) in the foreach loop. Attentively look at the c:gmlimport function I posted.